# tutorials for angular2 fullstack from scratch

Tags: express, angular, typescript, mongoose, angular-fullstack

Are there any tutorials (free or paid), anyone can recommend, that show how to create an Angular 2 full stack from Scratch. I've seen many packages and generators but would like to be able to know how to create my own structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of resources

Angular Docs: Start with Angular
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/

Angular Cheat Sheet : list of all syntax in Angular
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cheatsheet.html

Angular Style guide: How to structure your application
https://angular.io/styleguide

There are number of free plunkers created by Angular team which can be very helpful,

Modules : https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/ngmodule/ts/plnkr.html

Routing in depth : https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html

Hope these helps!!

Comment: Hoping to put together an Angular2 w/typescript, Express, MongoDB w/Mongoose, and Websockets w/Socket.IO. I have been lookiing into MEAN Stack as it is most closely to what I am looking to do. I could probably use recommendations of similar packages that you might think I could easily followed (and well documented) 

I basically come from strictly a coding background and didn't not have to worry much about setting up environment. But things have changed now and now I have to learn the options of client/server environments.